# Create Raster Output based on

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I have one population raster showing how many 'people' are in a grid cell (i.e. population count per cell)

And I have another raster for water available per cell.

I want an output raster that is classified based on how much water is available for 1 person in a cell. for example:

If 1 person has 1000 cubic meters of water for matching cells in the input rasters, that grid cell in the output raster will have a value of 1.

How do I achieve this in arcmap 10.2. I have the spatial analyst tool activated.

---

I feel this is a conditional query but I don't know how to do it. It should be something like this in english:

If water raster has cell values of <500, 500-1000, 1000-1700 and >1700 for each 1 person in a cell then output raster will record values of 1, 2, 3 and 4 respectively for cells with these values.

The issue is that population raster shows total number ofpeople in a cell, how do I factor this into the query which is looking at what is available per person.

Comment: what is the spatial resolution of each raster ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. They are all 30 minute (0.5 degree) resolution on WGS 1984 Coordinate System

Comment: You need to divide the raster population by the water availability (you can use the Raster Calculator tool, i.e. Raster Pop / Raster Wa) and then on the resulting output use the Reclassify tool to define your classes

Comment: below radouxju says water/population. which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the raster calculator to have the amount of water per person

```
Con("population" > 0, "water"/"population" , -1)
```

then you can use "[reclassify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000sr000000)" to set your threshold.

Comment: Thanks radouxju, GianlucaF says population/water. Which one?

Comment: Thanks again radouxju! water/popuation is what I need to do

Comment: I ran the raster calculator but I'm having nodata in some cells where there should both raster are overlapping

Comment: it could be due to a division by zero (no population). I've changed the code to avoid this issue.

Comment: Hi radouxju, the raster calculator provided data this time. but attempt to classify still not working properly, it is not displaying the new integer values.

Comment: I had to convert the raster to integer and build its attribute table. Re-ran the reclassify function and it worked fine. Thanks alot.